# Eclipse formatter : How to add whitespace between code and line comment

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, comments, whitespace, formatter

On Eclipse (i use Kepler SR-2 version), i don't find in Code Style / Formatter option how i can automatically add a whitespace character between code and line comment. Here is an example:

Before the formatting:

```
class MyClass {// This my class
...
}
```

After the formatting:

```
class MyClass { // This my class (a whitespace caracter should be added after the {)
...
}
```

Any clue?

Regards